# jQuery - AJAX call in success block of an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am doing an AJAX call, using the jQuery ajax plugin, and in the success block, I do another AJAX call. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: <someUrl>,
    data: {
        id: <someParam>
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: <someOtherUrl>,
            data: {
                id2: <someOtherParam>
            },
            success: function (checkoutData) {
                //do something
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {}
        });
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {}
});
```

**UPDATE**: The code is just pseudo-code, I am more concerned about the concept of calling AJAX within an AJAX success block.

I am noticing some weird behaviour on my page. It seems like the first AJAX call sometimes fails to call the URL, but does not return any error (I tried catching it in the error block). Is there something I should be careful about?

Thanks,
Iraklis

Comment: data: {
        id: ,
    }, second argument cannot be empty.

Comment: Thanks, Oyeme, this is just pseudo-code but I updated it :-), this is not the issue...

Comment: I updated the code, but in any case it is just pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

Is weird because AJAX is asynchronous not synchronous. Try to use `complete` instead of `success`.

```
var value = null;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: <someUrl>,
    data: {
        id: <someParam>
    },
    success: function (data) {
        value = data
    },
    complete: function() {
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: <someOtherUrl>,
            data: {
                id2: <someOtherParam>
            },
            success: function (checkoutData) {
                value = checkoutData
            },
            complete: function() {
                //process here
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {}
        });
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {}
});
```

Comment: In your answer, you also miss a parameter, but like the OP said, this isn't the problem.

Comment: Did you try using my example (from begin to end) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are three properties I would explicitly set if I were you. Their absence (esp. cache:false) when doing an ajax GET is **sometimes** the cause of odd behavior.

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
cache:false
```

I am assuming here that you are sending in json and getting json back as a response

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it had nothing to do with the nested AJAX request. It was just a combination of mis-assigned ID's and classes. My bad, I am sorry about that and I thank you all for your answers and the effort you put into this question.